# How to get the value of the keys in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-structures, higher-order-functions

I have an array of objects that is structured like this:

```
import icon1 from '!!raw-loader!../../../icon1.svg';
import icon2 from '!!raw-loader!../../../icon2.svg';
import icon3 from '!!raw-loader!../../../icon3.svg';
import icon4 from '!!raw-loader!../../../icon4.svg';
import icon5 from '!!raw-loader!../../../icon5.svg';

export const CustomIcons = [
  {
    home: 'icon1',
    homeIcon: (icon)
  },
  {
    series: 'icon2',
    seriesIcon: (icon2)
  },
  {
    explorer: 'icon3',
    explorerIcon: (icon3)
  },
  ...
];
```

In the constructor of my module I want to use the values like this:

```
export class IconRegistryModule {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    CustomIcons.forEach(icon => {
      iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral(Object.keys(icon)[0], sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(Object.keys(icon)[1]));
    });
  }
}
```

So the addSvgIconLiteral method should look like this for the first run of the forEarch:

```
iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral('the value of the key home', sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('the value of the key homeIcon');
```

Comment: Why is the structure like that?

Comment: This type of structure would make everything much more easy to deal with: https://jsfiddle.net/uy9tmqcr/

Comment: Do you have a better solution? I found the code like this and try to adjust it now.

Comment: @TKoL Is this not the same? I cant see any difference?

Comment: every object in your array has a different set of keys. Every object in my array has the same set of keys.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I noticed it now. Hmm, I still can't get the values ​​...

Comment: Yes, that's not the solution the your entire problem, that's just a much better starting point to make it easier for you to solve your problem. An array of objects where every object has different keys is hard to deal with. An array of objects where every object has the same keys is easy to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys(icon)[0]` just gives you the key. You can use the key as index on the icon object.

You can do `icon[Object.keys(icon)[0]]` to get the value.

(Of course you will need to make sure that the first property is always the one holding the url. In that sense it would probably be better to base the structure on an interface with consistent naming like suggested in the comments.)

**Edit:**
Using an interface should look somewhat like this:

```
export interface CustomIcon {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

export const CustomIcons: CustomIcon[] = [
  {
    name: 'icon1',
    icon: (icon1)
  },
  {
    name: 'icon2',
    icon: (icon2)
  },
  ...
]
```

Then in the constructor (Object.keys not required anymore):

```
constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  CustomIcons.forEach(icon => {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIconLiteral(icon.name, sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(icon.icon));
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok this works for me. However, I would like it to be cleaner. I have adjusted it as mentioned in the comments so that every key has the same name and only the values ​​differ. But it still only works the way you suggested it here.

Comment: @Codehan25 I added an example of how to use an interface with this. In that case `Object.keys` is not required anymore.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for get object keys in array.

```js
CustomIcons.map((data) => {
console.log(Object.keys(data));
});
```

Comment: This way I just get the keys of each object like this: Array [ "name", "icon" ]

Answer (score 0):

Use Object.keys to get the values from each object

```
var keys = Object.keys(CustomIcons[i])
```

And then iterate through each element in the array with a for loop.

You can append each of these elements to a seperate 'key array' at the end of each
loop.